# hide checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table within a checkbox and what I want is, when the checkbox is checked and i press the delete button the table must hide. So I tried this:

```
$('deleteButton').click(function() 
{
    $('input:checkbox:checked').parents($('table').hide());
});
```

But it didnt work, I hope someone can help me out with this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us your HTML, if possible in a jsfiddle, that will be easier.

Comment: I think you may wish to change `$('deleteButton')` to `$('.deleteButton')` or `$('#deleteButton')`. You are currently looking for an `<deleteButton>` element which I hope isn't on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Firstly, your `deleteButton` selector would match an element named `<deleteButton>`, which is obviously not valid. I'm guessing you meant it to be an `id` selector (`#deleteButton`) or a class selector (`.deleteButton`).

Secondly, this line will hide all of the `table` elements on your page:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').parents($('table').hide());
```

The reason for that is you call `$('table').hide()`, which will hide all of the `table` elements, and pass the result of that into the `parents` method (but do nothing with the result of the `parents` method). I think what you probably meant was to use `table` as a selector to the `parents` method:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').parents("table").hide();
```

However, if the `table` you want to hide is a descendant of another `table` further up the DOM, you probably want to use [`parentsUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/), or you'll end up hiding the ancestor `table` too.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Very stupid to forget the # for the deleteButton.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
    $('deleteButton').click(function() 
{
    $('input['yourcheckboxname']:checked').parents('table').hide();
});
```